# What's the use of git pull ---no-ff?

Tags: git, github

I tried pushing my local commits to the remote repo and it harshly denied my push and showed a fast forwarding error.

I tried using git pull but the same thing no results gained.

Tried git pull `--no-ff` and it worked.

But still don't know why fast forwarding is important why not just git push?

Comment: `--no-ff`tells git to avoid doing a _fast-forward_ on a merge _even_ if it is possible to do so (git is lazy.... if you ask to merge a branch _and_ you are standing on an ancestor of the branch you are trying to merge, git will avoid creating an _unnecessary_ merge commit and will simply _fast forward_ to the commit at the tip of the branch you are asking to merge... if you are _not_ on an ancestor of the branch you are trying to merge, git needs to perform a merge, no ff is possible).

Comment: @eftshift0: Absolutely correct, I just want to add something: Current versions of git can be configured to abort `git pull` by default, whenever a fast-forward is **not** possible. (`[pull] ff = only`). In such case the option `--no-ff` will be necessary to tell git that the non-fast-forwardable merge is intentional/desired. Only then git will actually perform the pull (and creating a merge-commit in the process).

Comment: @TTT yes, I made the same typo :-/ That should really have been "`git push --no-ff` is invalid. `--no-ff` is not supported by `push` (but by other commands, most notably `merge` – and by extension `pull`)

Comment: @TTT yes, I made the same typo :-/ That should really have been "`git push --no-ff` is invalid. `--no-ff` is not supported by `push` (but by other commands, most notably `merge` – and by extension `pull`)" I will delete the erroneous comment.

Comment: I think this question would be less confusing if it was changed to say "What's the use of git **pull** --no-ff?" ("pull" instead of "push".)

Answer (score -2):

Few options:

1. Without looking at your git server I can assume that your git administrator disabled the option to push as fast forward.
   It can be done with a `git hook` on the server
2. You have a local configuration for a specific branch to disable the ff

```
# Allow only nop-ff merge on a specific branch 
$ git merge --no-ff <branch_name>
```

3. Fast-forward merges can help keep your commit history clean.
4. `--no-ff` will display the tree in a way that can show you what commits were included in a certain branch

#### Fast forward example

[image]

#### NonFast forward example

[image]

Comment: "Disabled the option to push as fast-forward"? Huh? How are you going to push then? Fast-forward is the only way to push (well, with the exception of force-pushing). Also, there's a quote, but no source of the quote?

Comment: Yes it can be done - you can disable ff !!

Comment: But how are you going to _push_ if FF pushes are rejected? FF is the only way to _push_. That's a genuine question, I don't understand it!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the question title is just a typo, and should actually say "pull --no-ff" instead of "push --no-ff". But your answer seems to run with it and imply that you can use "push --no-ff" to send a message to the receiving repo to create a new merge commit. Am I interpreting this correctly?

Comment: Side note, even if you *can* do it in theory, what is the syntax of the push command? I get a syntax error with `git push --no-ff`.